# Write non-Pivot version of a query

Tags: sql-server-2005, pivot, pivot-table

Here is my table structure and some data:

```
CREATE TABLE Travel 
(
  ID int primary key, 
  Name nvarchar(25),
  City nvarchar(25),
  Month varchar(3)
)

INSERT INTO Travel
(ID, Name, City, Month)
VALUES
(1, 'Name1', 'Paris','Jan'),
(2, 'Name1', 'Rome','Feb'),
(3, 'Name2', 'Italy','Jan'),
(4, 'Name2', 'Rome','Feb'), 
(5, 'Name3', 'Los Angeles','Jan'),
(6, 'Name3', 'New York','Feb');
```

Can someone please help me write out the non-Pivot version to return the 'month' columns only when there is data (Assume the database is before SQL Server 2005).

Here is a sample query but it returns NULL data columns (Apr, May)

```
SELECT Name,
  max(CASE WHEN MONTH  = 'Jan' THEN City END) Jan,
  max(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'Feb' THEN City END) Feb,
  max(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'Mar' THEN City END) Mar,
  max(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'Apr' THEN City END) Apr,
  max(CASE WHEN MONTH = 'May' THEN City END) May
FROM Travel
GROUP BY Name

NAME    JAN    FEB       MAR     APR      MAY
Name1  Paris       Rome     (null)  (null)  (null)
Name2  Italy       Rome     (null)  (null)  (null)
Name3  Los Angeles New York (null)  (null)  (null)
```

Also, what would be the PIVOT version of the query, as there is no function to aggregate the column over?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do something like this:

```
DECLARE
    @v_sql varchar(8000)
BEGIN
Set @v_sql = 'SELECT name '
If exists (select month FROM travel WHERE month='Jan')
BEGIN
  Set @v_sql = @v_sql + ',   max(CASE WHEN MONTH  = ''Jan'' THEN City END) Jan'
End

If exists (select month FROM travel WHERE month='Feb')
BEGIN
  Set @v_sql = @v_sql + ',   max(CASE WHEN MONTH  = ''Feb'' THEN City END) Feb'
End

If exists (select month FROM travel WHERE month='Mar')
BEGIN
  Set @v_sql = @v_sql + ',   max(CASE WHEN MONTH  = ''Mar'' THEN City END) Mar'
End

If exists (select month FROM travel WHERE month='Apr')
BEGIN
  Set @v_sql = @v_sql + ',   max(CASE WHEN MONTH  = ''Apr'' THEN City END) Apr'
End

If exists (select month FROM travel WHERE month='May')
BEGIN
  Set @v_sql = @v_sql + ',   max(CASE WHEN MONTH  = ''May'' THEN City END) May'
End

Set @v_sql = @v_sql + ' FROM Travel GROUP BY name'

EXECUTE(@v_sql)

END
```

**Output:**

```
NAME     JAN           FEB
-------- ------------- -----------
Name1    Paris         Rome
Name2    Italy         Rome
Name3    Los Angeles   New York
```

Don't forget to check the **[Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d486/32)**